# Configuración Login JBOSS 7.1

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, jboss

Me gustaría saber como configurar el servidor jboss 7.1 para que el acceso a  listado de Punto Final requiera de login.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He podido encontrar algún tutorial, pero son de versiones antiguas o bien configurando la parte de tomcat, pero mi servidor no tiene la parte de tomcat, por lo que la configuración se debe hacer directamente en el jboss

Comment: Lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es: como se configura el login hacia la aplicacion de configuracion de Jboss?

Comment: Me refiero a poner un login o una restricción de acceso en el servidor de JBOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hablando del modo standalone, en la ruta standalone/conf/standalone.xml hay un tag xml en el que se relacionan varios archivos properties en los cuales se asocian los usuarios y contraseñas que va a manejar jboss para acceso a la web de configuracion o acceso de servicios EJB remoto entre otros puntos

`<management>
        <security-realms>
        </security-realms>
      </management>`

Supongo que para domain debe ser muy parecido, pero no lo he trabajado